# getting the updated value from an UPDATE query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an UPDATE Query :

```
UPDATE   FKMS_GNST_Transaction_Details
   SET Received_Quantity=Received_Quantity+(
                       CASE
                       WHEN (@int_Updated_Qty)>=(GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity)
        THEN GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity
                       ELSE (@int_Updated_Qty)
                       END)
      ,@int_GNST_Reference_Id=GTD.Transaction_Detail_Id   
  FROM FKMS_GNST_Transaction_Details GTD
 INNER JOIN #tbl_transactions tmp
    ON tmp.Transaction_id=GTD.Transaction_id
   AND GTD.Item_id=tmp.Item_id
```

I want to get the quantity which is added to the Received_Quantity field. That is, if `(@int_Updated_Qty)>=(GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity) then GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity` other wise `@int_Updated_Qty`.

How can we take this value (into a variable or any other way)? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
UPDATE   FKMS_GNST_Transaction_Details
   SET Received_Quantity=Received_Quantity+(
                       CASE
                       WHEN (@int_Updated_Qty)>=(GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity)
        THEN GTD.Quantity-GTD.Received_Quantity
                       ELSE (@int_Updated_Qty)
                       END)
      ,@int_GNST_Reference_Id=GTD.Transaction_Detail_Id   

--start gbn code
OUTPUT INSERTED.Received_Quantity
--end gbn code

  FROM FKMS_GNST_Transaction_Details GTD
 INNER JOIN #tbl_transactions tmp
    ON tmp.Transaction_id=GTD.Transaction_id
   AND GTD.Item_id=tmp.Item_id
```

The OUTPUT results can go

- into a table (real, temp or variable)
- to the client as a recordset

You can't assigned directly to a local variable